Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack/client'
I am using next.js 14 when I try to build the project then I get the following error, but when I run my project locally with npm run dev it works fine.
I stuck here for the last 1 day, I am trying to deploy my project.
repo: https://github.com/vishwas-babar/true-feeback/tree/version2
PS C:\Users\vishw\OneDrive\Desktop\next js\true_feedback> npm run build

> true_feedback@0.1.0 build
> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.14
  - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/action-client-wrapper.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack/client'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./src/actions/action.ts
./src/components/Signin.tsx
./src/pages/SigninPage.tsx

./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/fetch-server-response.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack/client'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/prefetch-cache-utils.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/create-initial-router-state.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-call-server.js
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/action-client-wrapper.js
./src/actions/action.ts
./src/components/Signin.tsx
./src/pages/SigninPage.tsx

./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/reducers/server-action-reducer.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack/client'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/router-reducer.js
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/action-queue.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/use-reducer-with-devtools.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-call-server.js
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/action-client-wrapper.js
./src/actions/action.ts
./src/components/Signin.tsx
./src/pages/SigninPage.tsx


> Build failed because of webpack errors
PS C:\Users\vishw\OneDrive\Desktop\next js\true_feedback> 


I found a solution for this. in my next app, I used the pages directory inside a src due to this it gave me this error. when I changed the name of the pages directory then this error was solved.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Leaving this here in case somebody needs it, as Vishwas says, remove any folder called "pages". I had a "pages" folder inside my components folder because that was the name of my component and this error was driving me crazy.
